Flutter, going back from screen2 to screen1 without reloading
Hi I am working with flutter in a mobile app that loads a list of house style images in a instagram kind of way, then the user can tap on any of the images, to see details, that will take it to another screen where they can add comments or like it, then use the activity back button to go back to first screen, that way it does not reload the screen, but I wan to modify the widget with the "like" count (in case the user like the post).
Is there a way to send back that info from the second screen to the first screen without reloading the whole page?
All the information that is presented on the first screen is coming from the server and save in and object List and past to a GridView.
The idea is only modify the Text widget with the like or comment count
Any way to do it? Thanks



In order to receive some help and suggestions, you need to share the code that's related to these views and relevant to your question.

Please add code, and share what state management tool are you using.

The ideal way would be to listen to a stream in the widget that needs to be updated in case there is a change of number of likes / comments.
In the second screen, instead, you trigger a future that updates the number of likes/comments and therefore the widget in the first page on background is updated automatically.
A stream also would help you to listen to other changes, for instance: what if someone else (not you in the second page) likes / comments the post? The data would get automatically updated as soon as the stream registers a change.
Otherwise, another simplest option that would work on your specific case would be to

use an object like NumberOfLikesAndComments in the first page to display the number of likes and comments
send the object from the first page to the second one with routing (for instance the second page constructor could be SecondPage(required NumberOfLikesAndComments nLikesAndComments) )
update the object in the second one if the user likes/comments (with addLike/addComment)

class NumberOfLikesAndComments {
int numberLikes;
int numberComments;
NumberOfLikesAndComments(this.numberLikes, this.numberComments);

void addLike(){
numberLikes=numberLikes+1;
}

void addComment(){
numberComments = numberComments+1;
}
}


